# Telerik PersistenceFramework: RadGridView PersistenceManager.StorageId

Tags: data-binding, telerik, persistence, dependency-properties, radgridview

I'm trying to use `telerik:PersistenceManager.StorageId` property on `RadGridView` to persist the component status in the local storage.

If I set the property like this:

```
telerik:PersistenceManager.StorageId="rgvItems"
```

all works fine but I would like to set the `StorageId` dynamically using binding.
To do that, I've tried to set the property like this:

```
telerik:PersistenceManager.StorageId="{Binding Path=StorageId}"
```

where `StorageId` is a `DependecyProperty` defined in the component `xaml.cs` file:

```
    public string StorageId
    {
        get
        {
            return (string) GetValue(StorageIdProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(StorageIdProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StorageIdProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("StorageId", typeof(string), typeof(vGridContainer));
```

and set in the component constructor like this:

```
    public vGridContainer(string storageId)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        StorageId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PersistenceManager.StorageId"]

        [...]
    }
```

With that code the grid view status is not persisted.

Am I missing something?

Thank you all in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried everything about binding property from *xaml* but nothing worked.

Finally I solved that issues setting the attached dependency property from code like this:

```
rgvCheckIn.SetValue(Telerik.Windows.Persistence.PersistenceManager.StorageIdProperty, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PersistenceManager.StorageId"]);
```

Now it works fine.
Hope that helps anyone that is experiencing the same issue :)